# Modifying xml attributes through python

Tags: python, xml, attributes

I have the following XML file in which the following information is present.

```
<PHYSICAL_TLINE>
    <Traces general_diff="0" z_array="0" s_array="0" w_array="0" etch_factor="0.35" TS_track2track="0" TS_DQS="0" TW_DQS="0" TS_byte2dqs="0" TS_byte2byte="0" TS_DQ="0" TW_DQ="0" dsl_offset="0" D="20" TS="7" TW="5"/>
<PHYSICAL_TLINE>
```

Is there a way to set the values of these elements through python? For example, if I want to change the value of s_array to 5 instead of 0?.
I know that there is the xml.etree set command but I'm not too sure on how to set the values of these attributes in the child through python.

Comment: Did you even attempt to google "python xml" ?

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922056/setting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-file-using-elementtree

Answer (score 2):

```
child.attrib["s_array"] = '0'
```

Assuming that child is the `<Traces/>` node.

**Edit:**
0 needs to be a string

Comment: `0` should be a string, `child.attrib["s_array"] = '0'`

Answer (score 1):

This documentation may be helpful for you:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Note 19.7.1.4. Modifying an XML File

Modifying some code like this should acheive the desired result:

```
for rank in root.iter('rank')
    rank.set('updated', 'yes')
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: Please provide code based off of the xml above and we may be able to help out :).